# Using Micosoft.CodeAnalysis(roslyn) to add existing C# projects to a solution file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, roslyn, solution

I have tried to use Micosoft.CodeAnalysis to add existing C# projects to an existing solution but it seems that adding projects in a solution is not supported.

```
MSBuildWorkspace wks = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();
Solution solution = wks.OpenSolutionAsync(  @"c:\users\...\RSolution.sln").Result;
 ...
solution=solution.AddProject(project.Id, project.Name, project.AssemblyName, project.Language); 
wks.TryApplyChanges(solution); //Solution File does not change
```

Do you know if it possible to add existing C# projects to an existing (an empty) visual studio 2015 solution using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis(Roslyn) and save the solution file to disk?

Answer (score 0):

[`MSBuildWorkspace` does not](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.Desktop/Workspace/MSBuild/MSBuildWorkspace.cs) override [`ApplyProjectAdded`](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces/Workspace/Workspace.cs,f724fbc308596976); Roslyn itself cannot do that.

Comment: Do you any other way to create Visual Studio solution file from existing C# project files?